# Neo4J: Importing a large Cypher dump

Tags: import, neo4j

I have a large dump (millions of nodes and relationships) from a Neo4J 2.2.5 database in Cypher format (produced with `neo4j-sh -c dump`), that I'm trying to import into a 3.0.3 instance.

However, the import process (`neo4j-sh < dump.cypher`) slows down drastically after a few minutes, down to a couple records per second.

Is there any way to speed up this process? I tried [upgrading the database as described in the manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/upgrade/), but the new instance crashes with an exception about a version mismatch in the store format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j 3.0 comes with a bin/neo4j-admin tool for exactly this purpose.

try `bin/neo4j-admin import --mode database --from /path/to/db`

see: http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/upgrade/#upgrade-instructions

The cypher dump is not useful for large database, it's only for smaller setups (a few thousand nodes) for demos etc.

FYI: In Neo4j 3.0 the cypher export procedure from APOC is much more suited for large scale cypher dumps.

#### Update

You can also try to upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3 first. E.g by using neo4j-shell

add `allow_store_upgrade=true` to your neo4j.properties` in 2.3

and then do: `bin/neo4j-shell -path /path/to/db -config conf/neo4j.properties -c quit`

If it is finished that backup of your db is on Version 2.3

Then you should be able to use `neo4j-admin -import ...`

Comment: Thanks Michael. Thats what I tried the first time, but unfortunately I'm getting an exception: 
`org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version '���+' that we cannot upgrade from`

Comment: I wonder if `store-utils` would help. Can it be used to migrate a store between major neo4j versions?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: No luck. The `neo4-shell` command finished silently in a couple seconds. When I tried to start 2.3 with the supposedly upgraded DB, I got a similar exception. `'/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version '���+`

Comment: OK, success. I was running the scripts from Docker containers, which (I guess) are not being cleanly shutdown when stopped. Performing the upgrades outside a container worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same symptom with my CSV import slowing to death.
My load-csv cypher script had too many rels.

So I divided my load in two. First create the nodes, then the relations and most connected nodes. HIH.

Back to your issue
First, try to increase the memory for the JVM. In NEO/conf, there is a wrapper file. At the beginning are the memory settings.

Lastly, from an instance w/ your data, export to multiple CSV files and import them in your new server.